# c - The permitted maximum of the "iovcnt" argument in "writev"?

Tags: c, unix

I've read man page for `writev` and found the ERRORS section notes that

> EINVAL ... the vector count `iovcnt` is less than zero or **greater than the permitted maximum**.

But how could I get the max value?

PS: On my OS (Ubuntu 14.04 x64) it seems to be 1024. I check it via the following code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

char content[4000];
struct iovec vec[4000];

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    // int cnt = 1024; // OK
    int cnt = 1025; // writev error
    int fd = open("tmp.txt", O_WRONLY);

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
        content[i] = 'a' + i % 26;
        vec[i].iov_base = content + i;
        vec[i].iov_len = 1;
    }

    n = writev(fd, vec, cnt);
    if (n == -1) {
        perror("writev");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I found in some manual page :

> POSIX.1-2001 allows an implementation to place a limit on the number
>   of
>          items  that  can be passed in iov.  An implementation can advertise its
>          limit by defining IOV_MAX in <limits.h> or at run time via  the  return
>          value  from  sysconf(_SC_IOV_MAX).   On  Linux, the limit advertised by
>          these mechanisms is 1024, which is the true kernel limit.  However, the
>          glibc  wrapper  functions  do  some  extra work if they detect that the
>          underlying kernel system call failed because this limit  was  exceeded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that `IOV_MAX` is not defined (got compile error) on my system, but `sysconf(_SC_IOV_MAX)` works.

Comment: Compile with `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE` to get limits.h to define `IOV_MAX`.